# MPMoviePlayer wrong activation state?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the built in MPMoviePlayerController for playing videos.I've run in to a problem when using two MPMoviePlayerControllers (Note that no two videos are played at the exact same time). I can play as many videos as I want on the first controller, dispose of it when I'm done, and then allocate another MPMoviePlayerController. As soon as I set the controlStyle on the second controller, I get a SIGABRT with

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'movie player  has wrong activation state (1)

I have searched online and found a similar problem on stack overflow. The guy said he had forgotten to remove the playback finished notification. I believe I have done this properly using [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];

I still get the crash. Rather frustrating!

I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to use two controllers as long as they aren't being played at the same time. I'd rather not have to dig in to AVPlayer stuff just to get videos working.

Thanks!

Edit: Commenting out the controlStyle assignment still results in a crash. Below is the posted callstack, along with a few important methods from the class.

```
- (void) makePlayer;
{
[player.view removeFromSuperview];
[player release];
player = [MPMoviePlayerController new];
player.view.frame = self.bounds;
player.view.hidden = YES;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
[self addSubview: player.view];
}

- (void) dealloc;
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
[player.view removeFromSuperview];
[player release];
[super dealloc];
}

- (void) setMovieByName: (NSString *) name;
{
[self makePlayer];
player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
[player setContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: name ofType: @"mov"]]];
[player stop];
[player prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(movieDimensionsKnown:) name:MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification object: player];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: player];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object: player];
}

- (void) playbackFinished: (NSNotification *) n
{   
player.view.hidden = YES;
if ([delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(moviePlayerImageViewPlaybackDidFinish:)])
    [delegate moviePlayerImageViewPlaybackDidFinish: self];
}
```

Comment: You should show some code so that we know how exactly you are creating and disposing of the movie controllers. By the way, what if you don't set controlStyle? You still get the exception, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my own problem. I had the release and nil for the movieplayer inside the viewDidUnload method of my video view. This doesn't get called with the view is removed from it's superview, so I just had to throw a release in at the same time I was hiding the video.

I'm still slightly confused as to why the issue occurred in the first place, because I was using two separately allocated MPMoviePlayers.

tldr: Make sure the first MPMoviePlayer is completely released before trying to allocate a second one.

Comment: Ok, so your problem WAS memory management, which was my point in the first place. I didn't test my code, only you can do that, but you ended going to where I pointed you to.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem. You are releasing `player` before you even allocate it. Basically, the first time the compiler goes through your code it sees `player` getting a retain count of -1 (because of the `release` call) and then going up to 0 again when you allocate it (because of the `new` call). So, when you try and set any property for the first time, there is no object to set a property to (`player` never has a retain count of 1).
What you should do is check for the existence of `player`and only if it already exists, then you release it.

Try making this change to your **makePlayer** method:

```
- (void) makePlayer {

if (player != nil) {

[player.view removeFromSuperview];
player = nil;
[player release];

}

player = [MPMoviePlayerController new];
player.view.frame = self.bounds;
player.view.hidden = YES;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
[self addSubview: player.view];
}
```

EDIT: Made slight change. `player` is an instance variable, so what you actually have to do is check if it has been set to an object already.

Comment: Sadly, this did not solve the issue :( i'm really stumped on this one. I wish apple had done a better job designing this class. Not really thrilled with the number of issues I've seen in it. Also, I believe the player = nil and release lines are switched in your above example